# Is a stack on AWS restricted to only 1 Cloud Formation template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am working to learn AWS Cloud Formation. The AWS Getting Started doc provides examples, but I would like to know whether a stack on AWS can be maintained by more than 1 template. At my company we have existing stacks. Can I use a template to create additional resources in an existing stack?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time: **1 template == 1 stack**.

If you're using nested stacks, then you can have **1 template for multiple stacks**.

But having multiple templates describing the resources needed in 1 stack isn't possible (nor logic if you ask me). If you want to create additional resources for an existing stack: just modify the template and use the "update stack" functionality. (If you can't find the template that was used to create the stack, you can fetch it from the console when selecting the stack or by using the `get-template` api)